# NHibernate: keyless entity class for logging table with AliasToBeanTransformer - good?

Tags: nhibernate, logging, mapping, entity, primary-key

I have a logging table in the database, without anything usable as a unique key, neither single nor composite. It's a plain dump-in table, like:

```
CREATE TABLE Logging
(
    Timestamp DateTime not null,
    AffectedItemID int not null,
    KindOfItem int not null, -- enum-like
    KindOfEvent int not null, -- enum-like
    UserName nvarchar(128) null,
    MoreDetails nvarchar(max) null
)
```

Mapping this to a persistent class in NHibernate results in serious problems, since a key is required, but none is present; the composite columns (without MoreDetail) aren't unique. I tried with a composite key first (all columns except MoreDetails). Returned rows from a query will be lost, if the composite key is duplicate, another problem will occur, if one or more key columns have NULL values (here UserName only) - I repeatedly got null elements in the result list (using NHibernate Criteria, with .List<LoggingEntryClass>()).

No chance to add a primary key, too much code already working with the table. There are also no child collections within or references to the log entries.

So, since no direct object query (Criteria, HQL or other) will work with this correctly, I tried a Projection with aliases and AliasToBeanTransformer. This seems to give correct results, but I am not sure if it bypasses the NHibernate session identity/key checks. I also changed the session type from normal to stateless.

The entity class still has the old NHibernate mapping with the non-unique composite key; I hope this will be ignored when materializing with AliasToBeanTransformer.

Any experiences with this method? Will it be ok for this purpose? (not that I am supporting keyless tables/entities, but sometimes I have to work with what I get...)

Comment: For this requeriment maybe `AliasToBeanTransformer` is the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Query and `AliasToBeanTransformer` as you do to work with this data. It doesn't matter if a mapping for this class exists or not and because a mapping is not possible without a key, you can throw the mapping away.